# awk and regular expressions confusion

Tags: awk

Having never used `awk` before on Linux I am attempting to understand how it matches regular expressions. For example in the past based on my experience the regular expression `/2/` would match 2 in all of the following lines.

1. This will match 2
2. This will not match 2

Now if I run the command `awk '{if(NR~2)print}' sample.txt` which has the contents

1. 2 will be matched
2. This will not match 2
3. 2 may be matched

The line that is matched is `This will not match 2` which indicates it is matching the line 2 because if I replace the command with `awk '{if(NR~3)print}' sample.txt` it matches `2 may be matched`. Now if I also run the command `awk '{if(NR~/^2$/)print}' sample.txt`, the matches the same exact line i.e. line 2.

However the source I am referring to at http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Htnno4CHVus#t=502s seems to indicate otherwise.

What am I missing and how is the command `awk '{if(NR~2)print}' sample.txt` different to that of `awk '{if(NR~/^2$/)print}' sample.txt`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition `NR~2` is checking whether the record number, NR, matches 2.  For a 2 or 3 line input file, the expression is equivalent to:

```
if (NR == 2)
```

Similarly with `NR~3`, of course.  Try:

```
awk '/2/'
```

That will print all lines where the text of the line (`$0`) contains a 2.  By default, a regular expression matches against the whole line; you could limit it to a particular field with `$3 ~ /3/`, for example.

An `awk` program consists of patterns and actions, where either the pattern or the action may be omitted.

```
awk '{ if ($0 ~ /2/) print }
     /2/
     /2/ { if ($0 ~ /a.*z/) print "Matches a.*z"; }'
```

The first line has no pattern; the action in the `{ ... }` is executed for each input line (but only some input lines will generate output because of the conditional.  All lines that contain a 2 will be printed.  (If there is no argument to `print`, it prints `$0` followed by a newline.)

The second line has a pattern but no action; all lines that contain a 2 will be printed again.  (The missing action is equivalent to `{ print }`.)

The third line has both a pattern and an action; all lines that both contain a 2 and also contain an 'a' followed by a 'z' will be remarked upon.

---

> How are these two commands different?
>
> ```
>  `awk '{if(NR~2)print}' sample.txt`
>  `awk '{if(NR~/^2$/)print}' sample.txt`
> ```

The first command will print line numbers 2, 12, 20..29, 32, 42, ... 102, 112, 120..129, ... 200..299, ...; all lines where the line number contains a 2.

The second command will print only line number 2 because the `/^2$/` constrains the value to contain start of string, digit 2 and end of string.

---

> I take it that means that the source is wrong?

Now I've looked at the YouTube resource, I think you must have misunderstood what it is trying to teach.  When it talks about `{if (NR~2) print}`, it should be saying it will print any *line number* which contains a 2; the video cites line numbers 2, 12, 20, 21, 22, etc.  It should not be saying any *line* which contains a 2; I think the video does say that, but the video misspoke (but the text was accurate).  The comparison against NR is not actually wrong, but it is aconventional; I'm not sure that I'd include regexes against NR in an introductory video describing `awk`.  So, the video appears to have a glitch in the audio but the text on screen is accurate, I think. I may still have missed something.

---

> The command `awk '{ if ($0 ~ /2/) print }` against the file say `sample.txt` with the contents I mentioned would only result in the output 2 will be matched. Is that correct?

That command, given the input:

```
2 will be matched
This will not match 2
2 may be matched
```

will print all three lines; they all contain the digit 2.

> I also thought that the action was `print` and the pattern was `$0 ~ /2/`.

No; the pattern was empty (because there was nothing before the open brace) — so all lines match it — and the action was the part in braces `{ if ($0 ~ /2/) print }`.  Now, the action contains a conditional, but that's a separate issue.

> Now the command `awk '/2/' sample.txt` would print all three lines. Is that correct?

Yes.

Comment: Awesome. That works as I thought it should. I take it that means that the source is wrong?

Comment: How is `awk '{if(NR~2)print}' sample.txt` different to that of `awk '{if(NR~/^2$/)print}' sample.txt`?

Comment: Jonathan: +1 - nice answer. @PeanutsMonkey: The match operator `~` is not generally used with `NR` (it's usually `NR == 2`). If you did `NR~2` it would also match `12` and `22`, etc., while the anchored regex would only match `2`.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler - Thanks and sorry for being a n00b at `awk` but I completely lost you at `where either the pattern or the action may be omitted`. I don't quite follow the examples shown thereafter because I would have thought that `awk` needs to reference a text file of some sort.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler. Okay I read the comments you made again so correct me if I am wrong in its interpretation. <br/><br/> The command `awk '{ if ($0 ~ /2/) print }` against the file say `sample.txt` with the contents I mentioned would only result in the output `2 will be matched`. Is that correct? I also thought that the action was `print` and the pattern was `$0 ~ /2/)`<br/><br/>Now the command `awk '/2/' sample.txt` would print all three lines. Is that correct?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler - Now the command `awk '/2/ { if ($0 ~ /a.*z/) print "Matches a.*z"; }' sample.txt` would not result in any output as there is no `a` unless it matches the `a` in `match` or `may`. Is that correct?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: yes; on the sample data, since there's no mention of 'azimuth' or 'adze' or 'lazy' (let alone quick brown foxes jumping over dogs), there'd be no data.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Why does `awk '{if($0 ~ /2/)print}' sample.txt` print all 3 lines? Sorry I thought the variable $0 represents the first line in the file hence the command is restricted or limited to the first line? If it returns all 3 lines how is this different to that of just `awk '/2/' sample.txt`?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler - So when you say pattern, does that mean variables such as NR, NF, etc?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler - Does $0 represent the start of the first line and 2 is the end of the total number of lines i.e. 0,1,2? I take it that I would only do that if I was aware of the number of lines. Not sure what advantage it serves though.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: `$0` is the whole of the current line; `$1` is the first field, `$2` is the second field, etc. NF is the number of fields in the current line, so `$NF` is the last field. NR is the current record number, aggregated over all files; FNR is the current record number in the current file. Etc. All this is found in an `awk` manual. To refer to the previous comment: NR, NF are variables; they are not the pattern per se. The pattern is an expression that identifies the lines to be acted on; the action is in braces and specifies what is to be done when the pattern matches. RTFM time!

Answer (score 1):

`NR` means the Number of the Record being processed... 
You are matching against line number 2.

Comment: I gathered as much. So I take it that the source is wrong then?

Comment: as Jonathan has shown: just using `/2/`  is enough, as by defaule it matches against the entire line, ie `$0==2` (as a literal), or `$0 ~ 2` (as a regex) .

Comment: oops, I didn't see Jonathan's answer until I refreshed the page, after posting my answer.

Comment: You're allowed to add alternative answers; no-one has a monopoly on answering any question.  Indeed, the timing indicates you got your answer in 11 seconds before I posted the first version of my answer.

Comment: The Youtube video refers to `NR` being the Number of Records in the file. He speaks this, and has is written on screen. This is not correct. `NR` means the current Record Number.  (he does, however, mention that `print NR` will print every line number.. Actually, his terminology in a bit misleading.. Awk processes records not lines. By default the Record Seperator (RS) is defined a a newline, so by default the Record happens to be a "line".